# iOS: Comparison between a pointer and an integer

Tags: ios, typedef

I'm not sure why I am getting this warning and am hoping someone can explain where I am going wrong.

In my .h file I declare an enum:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CalType) {

    DAY_CAL,
    WEEK_CAL,
    MONTH_CAL,

};
```

In my .m file I have this code:

```
if (self.myCalType == DAY_CAL || myButton.tag == 0) {

        [self.myDay setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.calendarY, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        self.myDay.currentDay = self.currentDayNumber;
        self.myDay.strDayName = self.strDayName;
        self.myDay.strCurrentMonth = self.strCurrentMonth;
        self.myDay.strCurrentYear = self.strCurrentYear;
        [self.myDay buildDay];
        [self.view addSubview:self.myDay];
        [self.arrMyObjs addObject:self.myDay];

        self.myCalType = DAY_CAL;

} else if (self.myCalType == MONTH_CAL || myButton.tag == 1) {


}
```

The first conditional does not throw a pointer->integer warning but the second one does. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Should add if I change the typedef to int rather than NSInteger I still throw the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is self.myCalType defined?
I just copied your code and re-ran - no warnings here, so I'm guessing you possibly did something like:

`@property NSInteger *myCalType;`

instead of

`@property NSInteger myCalType;`

Comment: Dang it, that was it. myCalType is a property of the view controller. Nice catch. I was so focused on the TypeDef being wrong I didn't look at the property value. : D

Rewards coming your way as soon as SO let's me.

Comment: While I'm thinking of it, why no warning on the first check though?

Comment: I don't have an answer there, but if i had to guess - perhaps the 1st element in the enum listing is not only an element (constant), but it's also the head of the enum "object", so the compiler misses it when you compare a pointer to the 1st item in an enum, but not the subsequent ones.

Comment: We'll go with that. : D

Comment: The first value in an enum defaults to 0, so the compiler interprets the comparison as if you were checking for NULL in the first case.